# Using string literals as parameters to template tags in Django templates

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

One of the things I find myself doing often is passing string literals as parameters to template tags or functions; for instance:

```
{% url my-url 'my_param' %}
```

Unfortunately, the django template engine doesn't let you do this.  So I find myself doing this a lot in my view code:

```
my_context_dict['MY_PARAM'] = 'my_param'
```

and then in my view code:

```
{% url my-url MY_PARAM %}
```

Or creating a series of URL mappings, which I personally try to avoid.

Is it possible to use a string literal in Django templates?  Or possibly a more elegant solution?  I haven't seen anything on here or in the documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This feels wrong but is right.

```
<a href="{% url someting "param1" "param2" %}">text</a>
```

The nested `""`'s don't seem like they should work.  They do.  The Django `{% %}` material is simply pulled out of the HTML without regard for surrounding context.  So the "duplicated" `"`'s aren't really duplicated at all.

Comment: what changes are required in url.py urlpatterns ?

Answer (score 12):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
{% url my_view "my_param" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very wierd - I have a django project that uses single quotes to pass a string value and it functions just fine.

```
<a href="{% url categories 'vendor' %}"</a>
<a href="{% url categories 'crew' %}"</a>
```

On further investigation it turns out [this has changed in django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#overview). It now requires the quotes even around the url pattern name.