# url template tag in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, templatetags

I was trying to use the url template tag in django, but no lucky,

I defined my urls.py like this

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^analyse/$',              views.home,  name="home"),
    url(r'^analyse/index.html',     views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^analyse/setup.html',     views.setup, name="setup"),
    url(r'^analyse/show.html',      views.show,  name="show"),
    url(r'^analyse/generate.html',  views.generate, name="generate"),
```

I defined the url pattern in my view like this

```
{% url 'show'%}
```

then I got this error message

> Caught an exception while rendering:
> Reverse for ''show'' with arguments
> '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not
> found.
>
> Original Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/template/debug.py",
> line 71, in render_node
> result = node.render(context)   File
> "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
> line 155, in render
> nodelist.append(node.render(context))
> File
> "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
> line 382, in render
> raise e NoReverseMatch: Reverse for ''show'' with arguments '()' and
> keyword arguments '{}' not found.

I am wondering why django failed to render? what is the right way to define it in the tempalte?

Answer (score 13):

**IMPORTANT: this was for django 1.4. At django 1.5 it is just the opposite.**

try using url names without quotes

```
{% url show %}
```

not this

```
{% url 'show'%}
```

Comment: Bad idea. That way of using the URL template tag is deprecated and won't work in Django 1.5.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is your single quotes around 'show'.  Change this to "show" and it should work out for you.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854406/using-string-literals-as-parameters-to-template-tags-in-django-templates)

Comment: It's never worked for me, with single or double quotes. Removing the quotes works, it's odd. 1.5 works with double quotes.

Comment: Single quotes work just fine, Django 1.6.   Just make sure to put your parameters *outside* of the quotes!    Took me forever to find that bug, the template system happily generated empty URLs with no error indication.

Answer (score 3):

You maybe have some views not implemented yet. It looks like the template engine tries to find all views from the patterns in urls.py when the {% url ... %} filter is used.

It usually shows an error for your last pattern in urls.py.

Try comment out every url pattern you did not implement yet.

Also make sure you use the full path:

```
{% url myapp.views.home %}
```

The url template filter looks really unstable. Try to keep [future compatibility](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to be a little more specific on which view you're trying to use:

```
{% url appname.views.show %}
```

Comment: I'm trying to learn about this feature - what is it called? I searched Django-Project's documentation on Templates and they make no mention of `{% url .... }`

Answer (score 0):

For what is is worth, I had the same issue and while I do not remember the reason why now, this resolved it for me. Example from a [SCRUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29) app I was working on.

```
url(r'^$', 'scrum.views.index',  name='scrum-index'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.5 or above:

```
{% url 'show'%}
```

Django 1.4 or below:

```
{% url show %}
```

*You can see [Django 1.5 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/1.5/).