# Problems with django url template tag, {% url %}

Tags: django, django-templates

Hello I am trying to pass different urls from my site into a template.

I thought it would be done by using this in the template

```
{% url myappname.module.views.urlfunction %}
```

but that returns an error, saying that **"Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'"**

I am not sure what that means. I followed this example [url template tag in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777612/url-template-tag-in-django-template)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', 'myappname.module.views.start'),
```

and this is what I have entered in my template

```
{% url myappname.module.views.start %}
```

I have also tried this url pattern and template combo to no avial:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', 'myappname.module.views.start', name="home"),

{% url "home" %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You're receiving an error when using {% url "home" %}? That's the correct way to call a named URL in a Django template.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was correct and this is frustrating. I get the error **Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In last example instead of

```
{% url "home" %}
```

try

```
{% url home %}
```

without quotes

Comment: thanks that works. I understand why that was necessary when all of the example I see use quotations? Do you have an explanation?

Comment: Have no idea - I always use it as I told here without any quotes etc.

Comment: @sequoia: [Check out the section on forwards compatibility here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url).

Comment: This has been changed in Django 1.5. The name of the url should be given in quotes.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 2):

add the following line in the top of the template:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

It will support the pattern

```
{% url "VIEW_NAME" args... %}
```

Answer (score -3):

In all seriousness, I would consider **not** using the {% url %} scheme in django for simple cases.  They are designed to provide some sort of flexibility that you will likely never take advantage of, and they are almost guaranteed to waste hours of your time trying to work out how to do it 'correctly'.

Just use action="/login/" or action ="/home/" and spend the hours you saved doing useful things, like writing code.