# django - url tag not working

Tags: python, django, url

I have this form:

```
<form action="{% url create_question %}" method="post">
```

and this url.py

```
url(r'^neues_thema/(\w+)/','home.views.create_question',name="create_question"),
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Reverse for 'create_question' with arguments '()'
 and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**: what i want to do is: the user submits the form, and i want to take the titel of question which user is creating and put it into url. then url will look like: `neues_thema/how-to-make-bread/`. how can i give that parameter to `{% url create_question ??? %}` dynamically while submitting the form

this thread [url template tag in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777612/url-template-tag-in-django-template) didnot help me.

Comment: Which version of Django?

Comment: You want redirect user to `neues_thema/how-to-make-bread/` after submitting form with field `question` == "how to make bread"?

Comment: @imkost, yeah, almost, with field titel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't need any parameters to `{% url %}` in your template.

You can add function to your `views.py` for creating questions, that will redirect user to question page after success:

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^neues_thema/', 'home.views.create_question', name="create_question"),
url(r'^neues_thema/(?P<title>\w+)/', 'home.views.question', name="question"),
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render

def create_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['title']
        # some validation of title
        # create new question with title
        return redirect(reverse('question', kwargs={'title': title})


def question(request, title):
    # here smth like: 
    # question = get_object_or_404(Question, title=title)
    return render(request, 'question.html', {'question': question})
```

template with form for creating question:

```
<form action="{% url create_question %}" method="post">
```

---

Answering your "what am i doing wrong?". You are trying to render url by mask `neues_thema/(\w+)/` with this: `{% url create_question %}`. Your mask needs some parameter (`(\w+)`), but you are putting no parameter. Rendering with parameter should be `{% url create_question title %}`. But the problem is: you don't know the `title` while rendering page.

Comment: wow!! you hit the point man! you found my problem exactly! thank you thank you

Comment: I must say: why i love django is that the people who speak django are so lovely and honest and ready to help no matter what the problem is. I v never seen a community like this before. i am soo happy with django/python because the community makes me feel confident.

Answer (score 3):

Your url regular expression expects a parameter, your template should be like:

```
<form action="{% url create_question some_user_name %}" method="post">
```

[See **url** on **Built-in template tags and filters** docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: Drop parameter from url: `url(r'^neues_thema/$','home.views.c...`

Comment: but, i want the url lok like: ``neues_thema/blablablablabla``

Comment: template should be consistent with url. To generate `neues_thema/blablablablabla` you should write `{% url create_question  "blablablablabla" %}` in template.

Comment: can i give ``blbalablab`` dynamically?

Comment: @doniyor you want parameter in url and don't want to use parameter for building a url?

Comment: @doniyor, yes you can set parameter dinamically, in see answer `some_user_name` should be sent to template context.

Comment: answering your edit, you should add `how-to-make-bread` to context dictionary template and apply my answer. Bye.

Comment: thanks, but is there no regex way to do this: ``word_(\w*)`` should call function ``function`` in views ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
url(r'^neues_thema/(?P<user>\w*)$','home.views.create_question',name="create_question"),
```

and in your views

```
def create_question(request, user=None):
```

Comment: I'm thinking ... sure this is a way to avoid OP error? I have not tested it, but, I think that django will miss parameter also when regular expression is `W*`. Have you test it?

Comment: still requires the paramater

Comment: @danihp It will not. Thats the reason we have the `$` at the end.

Comment: i understand it is not working - are you getting the same error ?

Comment: yeah. the same error @karthikr. is there no regex way to do this: ``word_(\w*)`` should call function function in views ?

Comment: Well you can do it, but it is not a clean way to program. check 2 things for me :  1) In URL Patterns, how have you specified the pattern ? 2) Does `home/views.py` have a function `def create_question(request, user=None):` ?

Comment: @karthikr, 1) ``r'^neues_thema/(\w*)/'`` 2) yes, i have.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30625/discussion-between-doniyor-and-karthikr)

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this `{% url 'home.views.create_question' alhphanumeric_work %}`. It should work.

Comment: The alphanumeric_work is a variable that you have passed to the template. Sorry didn't see the (w) mark in the url. You will have to put the alphanumeric code as variables like I have done above or string

Comment: cannot do that dynamically. this is the problem now.

Comment: Why can't you do that dynamically. Its a variable,so just set that value dynamically.