# Show list of objects which have a reference to another model

Tags: python, html, django, view

I am trying to make a simple django app which will display a list of forums on the main page and when a user clicks on a forum title to be taken to the posts which belong to that forum

Here's the code for the post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
text = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(
    default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(
    blank=True, null=True)
forum = models.ForeignKey('Forum') # referinta la Forum
upload = models.FileField("Upload a file", upload_to = 'media', null=True, blank=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

And the code for the forum model:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The code in the views.py :

```
def forum_list(request):
forums= Forum.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
return render(request, 'students_platform/post_list.html', {'forums': forums})

def post_list(request):
     posts=Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
return render(request, 'students_platform/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Finally, i have a post_list.html file which looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Informatii despre examene</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1> Informatii despre examene</h1>

    <h2> Bine ati venit! </h2>
    </div>
{% for forum in forums %}
<div>


    <h1><a href="">{{ forum.title }}</a></h1>
    <p>{{ forum.text|linebreaks }}</p>

</div>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

How can i edit the html file so that each time i click on a forum title to take me to the posts which were added to that forum?

Comment: In your template, you need to add the urls for your forums in the href=""  See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777612/url-template-tag-in-django-template

Comment: @joelgoldstick I think she means url to admin

Answer (score 0):

Add to your PostModelAdmin `list_filter = ('forum',)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:yourappname_post_changelist' %}?forum__id__exact={{ forum.id }}">{{ forum.title }}</a>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls