# Running virtualenv on Django app kills my urls

Tags: django, django-templates, virtualenv, django-urls

I have a fully functioning Django project (not in a virtualenv) which has url patterns like

```
url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.Dashboard', name="dashboard"),
```

Which are used in templates like

```
{% url 'dashboard' %}
```

I am moving it into a virtual environment, however when I activate the venv using `source venv/bin/activate`, all my URL tags give

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for ''dashboard'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

If I remove the single quote marks it removes this error e.g. `{% url dashboard %}` is fine. However without these quotes urls like `project-create` fail when virtualenv is deactivated.

Any ideas what I should be looking at? Should be removing all the quotes and renaming my composite urls (e.g. `project-create ==> ProjectCreate`)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make sure that you are using same django versions inside virtualenv as outside of it?

Comment: Yes, that was the 97th thin I tried when diagnosing this... :) reinstalled django on the system and the virtual env using the same requirements  txt

Comment: try using debug=true and see the urls that are given in error. Also, paste the screenshot somewhere, so that we can have a look as well.

Comment: Debug is already true... It' occurs for **any** named URL where the name is single quoted in the URL template tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting double quotes instead of single ones, and see if its working. As its mentioned here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/854446/808236

Comment: Thanks anyway - I have tried but this does not fix the NoReverseMatch problem.  (The linked SO post double quotes the parameters not the url).  I think I'll just have to remove the single quotes and rename urls that fail.  In the meantime I may post a bug on the django-users group.