# Django: passing raw string from html to url

Tags: python, django

I understand that

```
<a href="{% url 'home:about' id %}">About</a>
```

passes the variable "id" to url file.

However, what should I do if I want to pass a raw string? For example, if I want to pass the string 'hello' to url, how should I put the string 'hello' in there?

For example, I tried

```
<a href="{% url 'home:about' 'hello' %}">About</a>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried double-quotes instead of single-quotes as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854406/using-string-literals-as-parameters-to-template-tags-in-django-templates)?

Comment: What doesn't work? Post error messages in case you're getting errors.

Comment: I found the answer in another post and marked this as a duplicate, but thank you for the comments anyways. As @schwobaseggl suggested, it turned out that I need to use double quote instead of single quote. So it should be `<a href="{% url 'home:about' "hello" %}">About</a>`